# How to check to see if 'dst' path exist in PYthon

Tags: python, shutil

```
elif user == str(3):
    src = input("Enter the location of the file you wish to copy: ")
    print('\n')
    dst = input("Next, enter the location where you wish to copy the file to: ")
    if os.path.isfile(src):
        while count < 1:
            shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
            print('Copy successful')
            count = count + 1
    else:
            print('One of your paths is invalid')
```

What is the best way to check if path exist and file does not exist within the dst variable..

P.S: My apologies if this is a noobish question, but the best way to learn is to make mistakes!

Comment: Side question: Coming from C# and UNIX, where switch statements are possible, is it still good etiquette to use if statements since Python does not truly support switch-case?

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.exists(dst)`

[See the Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.exists#os.path.exists)

This would simply help you make sure the destination file exists or not, helping you avoid overriding an existing file. You may also need to tease out missing sub-directories along the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

if os.path.exists(dst):
    do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.path.exists(dst) as shown below:

```
import os

# ...

elif user == str(3):
    src = input("Enter the location of the file you wish to copy: ")
    print('\n')
    dst = input("Next, enter the location where you wish to copy the file to: ")
    if os.path.isfile(src) and os.path.exists(dst):
        while count < 1:
            shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
            print('Copy successful')
            count = count + 1
    else:
            print('One of your paths is invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

First break your destination path down into a list of folders.
See the first answer here: [How to split a path into components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167154/how-to-split-a-dos-path-into-its-components-in-python).

```
from os import path, mkdir

def splitPathToList(thePath)
    theDrive, dirPath = path.splitdrive(thePath)
    pathList= list()

    while True:
        dirPath, folder = path.split(dirPath)

        if (folder != ""):
            pathList.append(folder)
        else:
            if (path != ""):
                pathList.append(dirPath)
            break

    pathList.append(theDrive)
    pathList.reverse()
    return pathList
```

Then pass the list to this method to reassemble the list into a path and ensure that each element on the path exists or create it.

```
from os import path, mkdir

def verifyOrCreateFolder(pathList): 
    dirPath  = ''
    for folder in pathList:
        dirPath = path.normpath(path.join(dirPath,folder))
        if (not path.isdir(dirPath)):
            mkdir(dirPath)

    return dirPath
```