# Path manipulation in python

Tags: python

I have looked on Stack Overflow everywhere but I cant find a solution to this problem.

Given that I have a folder/file as string: `"/path1/path2/path3/file"` how can I get the parent folder and its parent folder. In other words if I want to traverse up one level `"/path1/path2/path3"` or two levels `"/path1/path2"` how can I get those string values from the original string path in python?

Please note that I **don't simply want the pieces** of the path (in other words not a list of `['path1', 'path2', 'path3']`) but instead `"/path1/path2/path3"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a dos path into its components in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167154/how-to-split-a-dos-path-into-its-components-in-python)

Comment: `os.path.realpath(__file__)` will give you string that contains path to your file, and then just apply string manipulation to shorten it.

Comment: [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)? and apply it `n` times to go up `n` levels...

Comment: No, "this is not what [he] asked for". Lol...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.path.dirname()` ([*doc*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)) is the way to go. It returns the directory which contains the object pointed by the path:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.dirname('/path1/path2/path3/file')
'/path1/path2/path3'
```

In this case, you want the "grandparent" directory, so just use the function twice:

```
>>> parent = os.path.dirname('/path1/path2/path3/file')
>>> os.path.dirname(parent)
'/path1/path2'
```

If you want to do it an arbitrary number of times, a function can be helpful here:

```
def go_up(path, n):
    for i in range(n):
        path = os.path.dirname(path)

    return path
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>> go_up('/path1/path2/path3/file', 1)
'/path1/path2/path3'
>>> go_up('/path1/path2/path3/file', 2)
'/path1/path2'
>>> go_up('/path1/path2/path3/file', 3)
'/path1'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module:

```
>>> path = pathlib.PurePath('/file1/file2/file3/file')
>>> path.parts
('/', 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file')
>>> os.path.join(*path.parts[:-2])
'/file1/file2'
```

So just put `path.parts[:-n]` for `n` levels up.

Alternatively you can use the [`parents`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) attribute:

```
>>> path = pathlib.PurePath('/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6')
>>> path.parents[0]
PurePosixPath('/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5')
>>> path.parents[1]
PurePosixPath('/file1/file2/file3/file4')
>>> path.parents[4]
PurePosixPath('/file1')
```

So to go up `n` levels just use `parents[n-1]`.

To convert a `*Path` object to a string just call `str` on it:

```
>>> str(path)
'/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6'
```

Answer (score 4):

additionally to all other answers, you can also use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function with the `os.path.pardir` variable which usually equals `..`.

```
>>> path = "some/random/path/to/process"
>>> parent = os.path.pardir
>>> grand_parent_path = os.path.join(path, parent, parent)
>>> grand_parent_path
'some/random/path/to/process\\..\\..'
```

If you don't want to repeat `parent` several times, you can use a multipled list:

```
>>> os.path.join(path, *([parent] * 3))
'some/random/path/to/process\\..\\..\\..'
```

The result is quite ugly, so you can use the [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.realpath#os.path.normpath) function to make it prettier:

```
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(path, *([parent] * 3)))
'some\\random'
```

**Important note**: Doing so, you are sure your code is portable

Answer (score 1):

[`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) will do it for you. There are many other interesting functions in there.

Comment: Split the pathname path into a pair, (head, tail) where tail is the last pathname component and head is everything leading up to that. How can I traverve two or 3 levels up?

Comment: @RFVenter Call the function multiple times on the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
'/'.join (originalPath.split ('/') [:-2])
```

It will take you 2 levels up.

Comment: This may fail, for example, if the path is a Windows path using `\` as separator.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about a Linux path. By the way, as a habit I always convert paths to Linux paths. But admitted, os.path is the generally accepted toolbox for the job. I like a small toolbox, though, sometimes I can't find the hammer anymore...

Comment: It can be resolved by replacing '/' by `os.path.sep`

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I agree, the string is specific and your answer is nice, obvious (duh) and concise. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) gives you the parent directory.

Comment: This is not what I asked for.

Comment: Yes it is what you asked for.

>>> `os.path.dirname("/path1/path2/path3/file")`
'/path1/path2/path3'

Comment: Citing the question: 'or two levels'

Comment: 2 levels: os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname("/path1/path2/path3/file"))
...

Comment: And 104 levels? OK, isn't what RFVenter asked for ;)

Comment: Write a function that takes a path and a level and applies level times os.path.dirname on the path?