# os.path.basename to outfile

Tags: python, os.path

For every input file processed (see code below) I am trying to use "os.path.basename" to write to a new output file - I know I am missing something obvious...?

```
import os
import glob
import gzip

dbpath = '/home/university/Desktop/test'

for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(dbpath, 'G[D|E]/????/*.gz') ):
print("current file is: " + infile)
```

**

```
   outfile=os.path.basename('/home/university/Desktop/test/G[D|E]                              
/????/??????.xaa.fastq.gz').rsplit('.xaa.fastq.gz')[0]

  file=open(outfile, 'w+')
```

**

```
  gzsuppl = Chem.ForwardSDMolSupplier(gzip.open(infile))
  for m in gzsuppl:
  if m is None: continue
...etc

file.close()
print(count)
```

It is not clear to me how to capture the variable [0] (i.e. everything upstream of .xaa.fastq.gz) and use as the basename for the new output file?
Unfortunately it simply writes the new output file as "??????" rather than the actual sequence of 6 letters.
Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Show a real example of a file path from which you would like to exact the basename from using `os.path.basename` and what you'd like the name of `outfile` to be if it were created correctly. Sorry, your code is somewhat worthless in its current state...it's not even indented properly.

Comment: Apologies, a real path could be /home/university/Desktop/test/GD                           
/AAML/DEAAML.xaa.fastq.gz  The output filename would be DEAAML.fastq.gz.  The indentation is correct in my file but I had trouble getting it correct here.

Comment: if `filepath = '/home/university/Desktop/test/GD /AAML/DEAAML.xaa.fastq.gz'` then `os.path.dirname(filepath)` would return `/home/university/Desktop/test/GD /AAML`. Is that what you want? You still havn't clearly described what the resulting `outfile`'s name should be.

Comment: Again apologies, I just updated my last comment to include the example output file.

Comment: There are hundreds of folders with 2 characters and within each of those folders would be several dozen more subfolders (all 4 characters).  The names of the files are 6 letters.xaa.fastq.gz.  The script is meant to iterate over all of those folders, performing the function to each input file and outputting to its respective folder.

Comment: Well, `os.path.basename(filepath)` returns `DEAAML.xaa.fastq.gz`, which is the same a the filename of the original. Unless you want to overwrite the original file, to put `outfile` in the same folder you will need to create a different name for it, or put it in a different directory folder where the name won't conflict with an existing file's name.

Comment: DEAAML.xaa.fastq.gz is one of several thousand input files throughout that directory structure.  `os.path.basename(filepath)` returns "??????" when I use `'/home/university/Desktop/test/G[D|E]                              
/????/??????.xaa.fastq.gz'`

Comment: I guess the question should have been how to search through multiple directories with multiple files, grab the "basename" and only use that  as the output filename after performing a basic function.   This is fairly straightforward as a bash script but I am forced to use python in this case.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now...working on it.

Comment: Thanks @martineau, my apologies again for it being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it will get everything upstream of the `.xaa.fastq.gz` in the paths returned from `glob()` in your sample code:

```
import os

filepath = '/home/university/Desktop/test/GD /AAML/DEAAML.xaa.fastq.gz'
filepath = os.path.normpath(filepath)  # Changes path separators for Windows.

# This section was adapted from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3167684/355230
folders = []
while 1:
    filepath, folder = os.path.split(filepath)
    if folder:
        folders.append(folder)
    else:
        if filepath:
            folders.append(filepath)
        break
folders.reverse()

if len(folders) > 1:
    # The last element of folders should contain the original filename.
    filename_prefix = os.path.basename(folders[-1]).split('.')[0]
    outfile = os.path.join(*(folders[:-1] + [filename_prefix + '.rest_of_filename']))
    print(outfile)  # -> \home\university\Desktop\test\GD \AAML\DEAAML.rest_of_filename
```

Of course what ends-up in `outfile` isn't the final path plus filename since I don't know what the remainder of the filename will be and just put a placeholder in (the `'.rest_of_filename'`).

Comment: Wow @martineau, thank you!  Give a few minutes to digest and incorporate :)

Comment: Note I using Windows which is why there's back-slash path separators in the printed result instead of forward-slashes.

Comment: Again, thank you very much @martineau for all your help - I have learned a tremendous amount.   Your code is extremely useful and here is what finally worked on my end with some hints from your code.    `current file is: /home/university/test/GD/AAML/DEAAML.xaa.fastq.gz
current file is: /home/university/test/GE/AARL/DEAARL.xaa.fastq.gz
current file is: /home/university/test/GE/AARN/DEAARN.xab.fastq.gz
etc...
   outfile=os.path.basename(infile).rsplit('.')[0]
   outfile2='/home/university/test/%s.sdf' % outfile
   file=open(outfile2, 'w+')`

Comment: that first bit is an example of some of the file structure

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the kind of input data you're working with, but here's what I *can* tell you:

1. The "something obvious" you're missing is that `outfile` has no connection to `infile`. Your `outfile` line uses the `??????` rather than the actual filename because that's what you ask for. It's `glob.glob` that turns it into a list of matches.

   Here's how I'd write that aspect of the outfile line:

   ```
   outfile = infile.rsplit('.xaa.fastq.gz', 1)[0]
   ```

   (The `, 1` ensures that it'll never split more than once, no matter how crazy a filename gets. It's just a good habit to get into when using `split` or `rsplit` like this.)
2. You're setting yourself up for a bug, because the glob pattern can match `*.gz` files which don't end in `.xaa.fastq.gz`, which would mean that a random .gz file which happens to wind up in the folder listing would cause `outfile` to have the same path as `infile` and you'd end up writing to the input file.

   There are three solutions to this problem which apply to your use case:

   1. Use `*.xaa.fastq.gz` instead of `*.gz`in your glob. I **don't** recommend this because it's easy for a typo to sneak in and make them different again, which would silently reintroduce the bug.
   2. Write your output to a different folder than you took your input from.

      ```
      outfile = os.path.join(outpath, os.path.relpath(infile, dbpath))

      outparent = os.path.dirname(outfile)
      if not os.path.exists(outparent):
          os.makedirs(outparent)
      ```
   3. Add an `assert outfile != infile` line so the program will die with a meaningful error message in the "this should never actually happen" case, rather than silently doing incorrect things.
3. The indentation of what you posted could be wrong, but it looks like you're opening a bunch of files, then only closing the last one. My advice is to use this instead, so it's impossible to get that wrong:

   ```
   with open(outfile, 'w+') as file:
       # put things which use `file` here
   ```
4. The name `file` is already present in the standard library and the variable names you chose are unhelpful. I'd rename `infile` to `inpath`, `outfile` to `outpath`, and `file` to `outfile`. That way, you can tell whether each one is a path (ie. a string) or a Python file object just from the variable name and there's no risk of accessing `file` before you (re)define it and getting a very confusing error message.

Comment: very useful feedback thank you.  I will incorporate your suggestions most definitely.  Good explanation for learning.