# Get file name from an opened file, not a file path

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

Let's say I opened a file called file1.mp3 in a PyQt5 app using the file dialog and assigned it to a variable like this:

```
song = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")
print(song[0])
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(song[0])
self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
```

How can I get the file name instead of a file path so I can display it in a statusBar? Or even better, is there a "now playing"-like function I could use or create?

Comment: Why not use split on a string to separate phrases inbetween “/“ and “.” characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a dos path into its components in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167154/how-to-split-a-dos-path-into-its-components-in-python)

Comment: I know how to split a path in regular python, but my PyQt program turns a path into a QUrl. Would os.path.split work the same way on a QUrl? Sorry, I'm still learning PyQt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several simple ways to get the name of a file:

- Using `QUrl`:

---

```
song, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")
print(song)
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(song)
self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
your_statusbar.showMessage("now playing {}".format(url.fileName()))
```

- Using `QFileInfo`:

---

```
song, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")
print(song)
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(song)
self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
filename = QFileInfo(song).fileName()
your_statusbar.showMessage("now playing {}".format(filename))
```

- Using `pathlib`:

---

```
song, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")
print(song)
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(song)
self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))

from pathlib import Path    

filename = Path(song).name
your_statusbar.showMessage("now playing {}".format(filename))
```

- Using `os`:

---

```
song, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")
print(song)
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(song)
self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))

import os   

filename = song.rstrip(os.sep)
your_statusbar.showMessage("now playing {}".format(filename))
```

or:

```
song, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")
print(song)
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(song)
self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))

import os   

_ , filename = os.path.split(os.sep)
your_statusbar.showMessage("now playing {}".format(filename))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Self-explanatory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). You just need to slice the string. And because you are learning, I'll slice it the wrong way, for you to find out why.

```
filepath = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")[0]
filename = filepath.split("/")[-1]

print(filename)
```

After that you can simply use

```
self.<statusbarname>.showMessage("Now playing {0} song or whatever".format(filename))
```

However, that will only work on "some" systems. If you want to use that application on a different computer, you should first normalize the path (some systems use // and others \ for folders) and then you slice it with a safe built-in command.

```
import os # Careful with this library, Read the documentation first
filepath = os.path.normpath(filepath) # Normalize it
filename = filepath.split(os.sep) # Slice it
```

The entire code should work like this:

```
import os
filepath = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Song", "~", "Sound Files (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav *.m4a)")[0]
print(filepath)
filepath = os.path.normpath(filepath)
song = filepath.split(os.sep)
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath)
self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
self.<statusbarname>.showMessage("Now playing {0} song or whatever and it was at {1} folder".format(song, filepath))
```

Answer (score 0):

programming is not magic, you have a file path i.e:
c://myfolder/song.mp3 - assuming your music files are named after the song, you must parse the url for the song name and set the status bar title/label to the song you are currently playing. I suggest you take a entry lvl course on python before mixing qt frameworks into it.