# PyQt5 - Return currently playing media name from QMediaPlaylist currentMedia() function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer, qmediacontent

I have this code in a function:

```
self.playlist.currentMediaChanged.connect(lambda: self.songChanged())
```

and it calls this function:

```
def songChanged(self):
    if self.playlist.mediaCount != 0:
        print(QMediaContent(self.playlist.currentMedia()))
        self.statusBar().showMessage(self.playlist.currentMedia())
```

Printing it returns

```
<PyQt5.QtMultimedia.QMediaContent object at 0x109458cf8>
```

And trying to show it in the status bar returns an error:

```
TypeError: showMessage(self, str, msecs: int = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QMediaContent'
```

How can I get the program to return the currently playing file name or song title in the playlist as a string to put in the status bar? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm still learning PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to connect the function evaluated to the signal, only the name of the function. The `currentMediaChanged` signal returns the current `QMediaContent`, then you must use that `QMediaContent` and get the `QUrl`, and then as I showed in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217347/pyqt5-get-file-name-from-an-opened-file-not-a-file-path) we get the following:

```
    self.playlist.currentMediaChanged.connect(self.songChanged)

def songChanged(self, media):
    if not media.isNull():
        url = media.canonicalUrl()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(url.fileName())
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding your error, the traceback says everthing:

> *argument 1 has unexpected type 'QMediaContent'*

[looking at the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html#showMessage) we see

```
void QStatusBar::showMessage(const QString &message, int timeout = 0)
```

that it expects a `QString` or simply `str` in python -> build a string:

```
self.statusBar().showMessage(str(self.playlist.currentMedia()))
```

---

but wait, their is more! 
Did you know that you don't need a lambda-function to connect your function:

```
self.playlist.currentMediaChanged.connect(self.songChanged) # <- no brackets
```

also [`currentMediaChanged` does provide the current `QMediaContent` - docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#currentMediaChanged):

```
void QMediaPlayer::currentMediaChanged(const QMediaContent &media)
```

meaning you can make your `songChanged`-function a bit smaller:

```
def songChanged(self, media):
  if media:
    print(media)
    self.statusBar().showMessage(str(media))
```

---

to get the file's name from the object you can use: `media.canonicalUrl().fileName()`

```
 print(media.canonicalUrl().fileName())
 self.statusBar().showMessage(str(media.canonicalUrl().fileName()))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I don't need a lambda, that was rather stupid of me. I applied your changes, but the status bar shows: <PyQt5.QtMultimedia.QMediaContent object at 0x106648c18> How can I change it so it shows a file name and not the object?

Comment: @chaNcharge: use `str(media.canonicalUrl().fileName())`

Comment: It is not necessary to use str() in PyQt5, all QString are mapped to str by default.

Comment: @eyllanesc, thx - I was not sure on this - because the python types seems to exist alongside with the qt-types. So I allways cast the the types when possible.