# Split string by escape character

Tags: python, split, unicode-escapes

I'm trying to split a string by the escape character in Python.

This is the way I've been trying to do it:

```
s = "C:\Users\as\Desktop\Data\pdf\txt\RTX_IDS_1DYS_20170610_0000_220279611-650000624200.txt"
s.encode("string_escape").split("\\")
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
s = "C:\Users\as\Desktop\Data\pdf\txt\RTX_IDS_1DYS_20170610_0000_220279611-650000624200.txt"
       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a dos path into its components in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167154/how-to-split-a-dos-path-into-its-components-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

prefix your string with `r` - that will turn it into a raw string, telling python that `\` is a literal `\`.

```
s = r"C:\Users\as\Desktop\Data\pdf\txt\RTX_IDS_1DYS_20170610_0000_220279611-650000624200.txt"
parts = s.split("\\")
print(parts)
```

Output:

```
['C:', 'Users', 'as', 'Desktop', 'Data', 'pdf', 'txt', 'RTX_IDS_1DYS_20170610_0000_220279611-650000624200.txt']
```

For more information on string prefixes see:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Thanks!! Also I'm iterating a list of strings. Is there a way to convert them to raw strings? How would it be possible to add the `r` in front of the string?

Comment: You only need the prefix for string literals (and you cannot add a prefix afterwards). If you have filled a str variable programmatically, special characters are already escaped internally, so no need for a prefix. You can check the escaping with ``repr``, example: ``print(repr(r"C:\users"))`` Output: ``'C:\\users'``