# Python: Search through string for substring for filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, search

I'm trying to write a function that searches through a very long list of files paths, given as a string. I want to be able to organize them based on which sub directory they are in and at the end I want to print the name and sub-directories of the file. For example, one of these strings might look like the following:

```
file_name = "\\StringA\\StringB\\StringC\\Name.cpp"
```

where `StringA`, `StringB`, and `StringC` are sub-driectories and `Name.cpp` is the file name.

Now for the function, how would I go about doing this without searching specifically for the string like in the following? I don't want it to be like this because there are a lot of options (~200) and I don't want to add 200 if statements if its not necessary. Thank you!

```
def get_location(file_name):
    if "StringA" in file_name:
        if "StringB" in file_name:
            if "StringC" in file_name:
                name = file_name.replace("\\StringA\\StringB\\StringC\\", "")
                dirA = "StringA"
                dirB = "StringB"
                dirC = "StringC"

    return [dirA, dirB, dirC, name]
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595356/13596037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a for loop while splitting the filepath?

```
file_name = "\\StringA\\StringB\\StringC\\Name.cpp"

li = file_name.split("\\")
print(li)
```

Output:
`['', 'StringA', 'StringB', 'StringC', 'Name.cpp']`

Comment: Thank you this worked perfect!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue where you want to use a regular expression[0] to match everything in the string before `Name.cpp`, and then operate on that token set. Once you find your match, you can use `os.path` to break the file path into its constituent directories.

[0] https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html