# Using pathlib, how can I split a Path object into a list or iterable of individual names, platform agnostic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Let's say I have a Path object like so:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/Users/Me/Desktop/Media/Pictures')
```

On posix systems, this returns a `PosixPath` object, and on Windows, a `WindowsPath` object.

Is there a nice, build-in Pythonic way to get this natively using `pathlib`?

```
>>> segments
['Users', 'Me', 'Desktop', 'Media', 'Pictures']
```

(Or if not a list, a generator is fine, too).

I know I could do this, but I don't like that it relies on `str` type conversion, and though I can't test this on Windows, I'm not confident it will handle backslash escaping well:

```
[x for x in str(path).split(pathlib.os.sep)]
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`path.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#accessing-individual-parts)?

Comment: Do you know how many times I've read the docs, and missed that? Sigh. Thank you! If you want to post an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: For future visitors, the answer in the linked duplicate question that specifically answers this one is https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741379/1214800

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you're going to mark this as a dup, please at least leave in the direct link to the answer to this specific question in the body, so that future visitors don't have to search for it. The dup is very old, and there a lot of irrelevant answers, and lots of folks don't read the comments.