# Python: check if list element is part of the file path

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
my_list = ['service', 'confidential']

path_list = ['/Users/id/work/service/number', '/Users/id/work/pager/duty', '/Users/id/work/rake/confidential', '/Users/id/work/service/number/items', '/Users/id/work']
```

Wanted to print only the following elements of `path_list` list.

1. /Users/id/work/service/number
2. /Users/id/work/rake/confidential
3. Users/id/work/service/number/items

I tried:

`[print(i) for i in path_list if i in my_list]` and

```
for i in path_list:
     if i in my_list:
         print(i)
```

Both the options aren't working, where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `any`:

```
[print(i) for i in path_list if any(x in i.split('/') for x in my_list)]
```

Output:

```
/Users/id/work/service/number
/Users/id/work/rake/confidential
/Users/id/work/service/number/items
```

The more efficient way is still:

```
for i in path_list:
     if any(x in i.split('/') for x in my_list):
         print(i)
```

Comment: Wow, that's fast. Thank you..
Could you please show me, how to  construct the list comprehension for it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, since my reputation is less than 15, I cant upvote or accept the answer at this moment

Comment: Just a heads up: using a list comprehension if you don't want to build a list is considered wasteful. Also, this will print a path that contains `'confidentiality'`, for example.

Comment: @timgeb Edited mine

Comment: `match_pattern = [print(i) for i in path_list if any(x in i for x in my_list)]`, this way, I can capture the matched items into another list, right ?

Comment: @ChelMS Nope, you would have to use `match_pattern = [i for i in path_list if any(x in i.split('/') for x in my_list)]`, otherwise it would be a list of Nones

Comment: I used `match_pattern.append(i)`, it worked, thanks for the alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to run loop on `my_list`.

try this:

```
[print(i) for i in path_list for j in my_list if j in i]
# /Users/id/work/service/number
# /Users/id/work/rake/confidential
# /Users/id/work/service/number/items
```

Comment: My bad, yes.. U12-Forward also pointed out the same, thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a heads up: using a list comprehension if you don't want to build a list is considered wasteful. Also, this will print a path that contains `'confidentiality'`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595356/3620003) answer to split the paths into their components, the rest is straight forward.

```
import os

def split_dirs(path):
    normed = os.path.normpath(path)
    dirs = normed.split(os.sep)
    return [d for d in dirs if d]
```

Demo:

```
>>> split_dirs('/Users/id/work/service/number')
['Users', 'id', 'work', 'service', 'number']
>>> split_dirs('/////Users//////id/work/service/number')
['Users', 'id', 'work', 'service', 'number']
```

Solution:

```
my_list = ['service', 'confidential']    
path_list = ['/Users/id/work/service/number', '/Users/id/work/pager/duty', '/Users/id/work/rake/confidential', '/Users/id/work/service/number/items', '/Users/id/work']

for path in path_list:
    if any(word in split_dirs(path) for word in my_list):
        print(path)
```

Output:

```
/Users/id/work/service/number
/Users/id/work/rake/confidential
/Users/id/work/service/number/items
```